# How can I add an input loop?

Tags: python, loops, input

```
classes = input("There are three types of classes in this game. Warrior, Wizard and Hunter. Pick one.")

if classes == "Warrior" or "Wizard" or "Hunter":
    print ("Good choice.. the "+classes+" will dominate your opponents!")
else:
    print ("That's not a class! Pick again!")
```

#Basically, I want to add a loop so it'll ask the question again.

Keep in mind I am using Python-3

Comment: you need to use a while loop and also the or statement is wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/3001761

Answer (score 0):

```
characters = ("Warrior", "Wizard", "Hunter")

while True:
  classes = input("There are three types of classes in this game. Warrior, Wizard and Hunter. Pick one.")
  if classes in characters:
    break
  else:
    print ("That's not a class! Pick again!")

print ("Good choice.. the "+classes+" will dominate your opponents!")
```

Comment: This was a quote from the original question:)

Answer (score 0):

```
classes = input("There are three types of classes in this game. Warrior, Wizard and Hunter. Pick one.\n")

while classes not in ("Warrior", "Wizard", "Hunter"):
  print ("That's not a class! Pick again!\n")
  classes = input("There are three types of classes in this game. Warrior, Wizard and Hunter. Pick one.\n")

print ("Good choice.. the "+classes+" will dominate your opponents!\n")
```